Impersonated token from keyclaok in Springboot
I am trying to  get impersonated token whenever the current token gets expired from the keycloak. With Springboot i am trying to  implement a solution in order to sustain the token between large scale microservices architecture. How can i achieve  it with securitycontext
Tried to pull it from SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(); but it doesn't give any details. Trying with generic specification of OAuth.
var authentication =  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
if (authentication == null || !(authentication.getCredentials() instanceof AbstractOAuth2Token)) {
    return null;
}
var accesstoken = (AbstractOAuth2Token) authentication.getCredentials();
/**

if accesstoken  is expired i have to get the impersonated token.
**/
request.getHeaders().setBearerAuth(accesstoken.getTokenValue());
return execution.execute(request, body);

